# Creating a mySQL view where each row is a specific column's value in the same row

Tags: mysql

I have a product table that contains product price information.  Instead of each row containing 1 price for a specific product, each row contains a specific product and 3 columns of prices for different quantities for that product.

I'm trying to figure out a way to create a view that will, in essence, split those 3 columns up into its own rows, as well as a column for each of the other product information.

Sorry I know that sounds kind of confusing, so here is the sqlfiddle I started: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4443/1

The view is declared incorrectly, of course, but If you scroll all the way down you can see in comments how I would like the view to look.

Thanks!

Comment: Fix your DB design first. Having a properly normalized design will basically make your question go away. Bad designs require bad code to compensate, which just makes everything far more complicated than it should be. You should NEVER be storing multiple pieces of information in a single field. That negates the point of using a relational database in the first place.

Comment: Thanks I guess I will normalize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, you can do this using `union all`:

```
create view v_products as
    select product_id, p.type,
           CONCAT(p.type, '|', p.size, '|', p.color, '|', '|price_qty_50') AS full_product_name,
           price_qty_50 as price
    from product p
    union all
    select product_id, p.type,
           CONCAT(p.type, '|', p.size, '|', p.color, '|', '|price_qty_50') AS full_product_name,
           price_qty_100
    from product p
    union all
    select product_id, p.type,
           CONCAT(p.type, '|', p.size, '|', p.color, '|', '|price_qty_50') AS full_product_name,
           price_qty_250
    from product p;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I followed your example and it works perfectly. :)